# Meta tag and javascript browser redirection - which has priority?

Tags: javascript, redirect, curl, meta-tags

I'm developing in PHP, using Curl to follow links to their final destination.  I occasionally reach a page with a meta tag redirection or a javascript redirection, and want to be smart enough to follow them.  If a page has both, which should I follow (i.e., which would fire first)?

Sample meta tag refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://location1.com/'">
```

Sample javascript refresh:

```
<script>
window.location.href='http://location2.com/';
</script>
```

Comment: I think in some cases it amounts to a race condition... sometimes one will happen first, sometimes the other. I've been bitten by this before.

Answer (score 13):

Just created this file ( let's call it `test.html` )

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://location1.com/'">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location.href='http://location2.com/';
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

You can copy and save it. Once you open it, you'll be directed to `http://location2.com`

Do note that if the `<script>` tag is not in the `<head>` tag, the `<meta>` tag gets executed first.

Answer (score 3):

Hexblot's answer is a good idea -- just try it out if you want to see what happens. However, when I did try it out, Chrome went to location2, and IE went to location1. So it seems to be implementation dependent. You might want to have this be a configurable option on your script. In practice, though, any site that has one redirect in a meta tag and a different one in a script, is (a) unlikely, and (b) not coded very well, as they have no idea where you'll end up.

Comment: I now see when both appear in a page, the meta tag is often surrounded by <noscript> with the same destination - intended as a backup for any visitors w/o javascript ability.

Comment: @MichaelB That is the only semi-reasonable reason to have both on the same page that I can think of, and the chances of the destinations being different are quite small, so you can probably choose one arbitrarily without much of a risk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a good way to detect which one would fire first.

The meta tag has the `content` attribute which can be used to specify a timeout. However, in JavaScript it is nearly impossible to detect when the redirect will happen as there are infinite ways to write it. At least not without executing it. Example:

```
var t = 100;
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href='http://location2.com/';
}, t * 2);
```